# Can I track the exact time/date that user "likes" or "unlikes" a Facebook App I create?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, datetime

I am creating a FB app and I want to know if I can track precisely when (date/time to the second) a user "likes" the page.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/likes):

```
GET /v2.1/{user-id}/likes/{page-id} HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
```

> ...
>
> Reading this endpoint returns an array of Page objects with the following additional field:

```
Name           Description
created_time   A timestamp indicating when the page was liked by this person.
```